# How do I pass content from a template to a layout in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a basic Express server:

```
// server.js:
var Express = require('express');
app = Express.createServer();
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', Path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('view options');
});
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
  response.render('welcome', {
    locals: {some: 'Locals'}
  });
});
```

With a basic jade layout:

```
// views/layout.jade:
!!! 5
html(lang='en')
  head
    title= pageTitle
  body
    h1= pageTitle
    aside(id="sidebar")= sidebarContent
    #content
      #{body}
```

And a simple page:

```
# views/welcome.jade:
// How do I pass pageTitle and sidebarContent out to the layout from here?
p
  Welcome to my fine site!
```

(In Rails, this might be something like `content_for` or a simple instance variable.)

Comment: While it's a cms based on DocPad, perhaps you'll find it useful as it has built in support for layouts and jade. https://github.com/balupton/docpad

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the tip above about dynamicHelpers, and the magic of closures, I found a fairly elegant solution that works without involving the request object.  The trick is to wrap the page title variable in a closure that provides a get() and set() function around it, and make that wrapper object the result of the page_title dynamic helper.

Create a property.js:

```
exports.create = function () {
    var value = null;
    return {
        get: function () {
           return value;
        },
        set: function (new_value) {
           value = new_value;
        }
    };
}
```

So calling create() returns an object with a get() and set() method on it, that get and set the closure variable.

Then, in your app's setup code:

```
    var property = require("./property.js");
    app.dynamicHelpers ({
        page_title: function () {
         return property.create ();
        }
    });
```

Since the dynamic helper's value is the result of calling its function, in your view and template, the page_title variable will be the wrapper object with the get() and set() functions.

In your view, you can then say:

```
- page_title.set ("my specific page title");
```

And in your layout:

```
title= page_title.get()
```

To simplify this a bit further, adding this to property.js:

```
exports.creator = function () {
    return function () {
        return exports.create();
    };
}
```

Lets you simplify the dynamic helpers declaration block to this:

```
        var property = require("./property.js");
        app.dynamicHelpers ({
            page_title: property.creator()
        });
```

Comment: One of the most practical uses of closures I've come across!

Comment: How did you actually use this in the view? I like this idea, but for me the set() function never gets called and get() is always null.

Answer (score 5):

Express does not have a preconceived notion of "blocks" or whatever they call that in in rails, but you can use a combination of helpers() and dynamicHelpers() to achieve something similar http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app-helpers-obj-

Locals passed are available to both the layout and the page view though

Comment: So the idea would be to add a dynamic helper that stores `pageTitle` in the request, which the layout can then read out? That sounds like a fine solution. I might even wrap it up as a middleware and publish it!

Answer (score 2):

layout.jade

```
# the following function is a safe getter/setter for locals
- function pagevar(key, value) { var undef; return (value===undef) ? locals[key] || null : locals[key] = value; }
block config
  #intended as a non-rendered block so that locals can be overridden.
  # put your defaults here... - use append in the child view
!!!
html
  head
    title=pagevar('title')
    meta(name='description',content=pagevar('description'))
...
```

page.jade

```
append config
  - locals.title = 'override';
  - locals.description = 'override 2';
  - pagevars('somekey', 'some value');
...
```

Easy peazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using this little snippet.

prop.js:

```
var hash = {};
module.exports = function() {
    return {
        set: function(key, val) { hash[key] = val },
        get: function(key) { return hash[key] }
    };
};
```

server.js:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({ prop: require(__dirname + '/views/helpers/prop') });
```

---

View:

```
<% prop.set('foo', 'bar') %>
```

Layout:

```
<%= prop.get('foo') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it in  locals: `{some: 'Locals', pageTitle: 'Welcome!'}`

Comment: I don't have `locals` from within that template. I'd have to keep a map of `{ template path: page title }` and look up the page title before rendering. There must be a way to specify it from *within* the template itself.

Answer (score 0):

For Express 3 template agnostic, works well with `express-partials`

```
app.use (req, res, next)->
  req.locals = {} unless req.locals

  res.locals.content_for = (k, v = null)->
    if !v
      req.locals[k]
    else
      req.locals[k] = v

  next()
```