# Dynamic sidebars with Node.js, Express.js and Jade

Tags: node.js, dynamic, express, helper, pug

I'm trying to write a dynamicHelper for Jade to check if a user is allowed to access a resource before actually accessing it. I have the module to perform the checks which returns true or false when called with the url and username of the resource to be accessed, but I can't get the helper working with parameters?

dummy view:

```
if(hasAccess.check("/url", "username") == true)
  li access
else
  li no-access
```

Helper:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  hasAccess: function() {
    return access;
  }
});
```

Access-function:

```
var access = function() {
  return {
    check: function(url, user) {
      return mymodule.hasAccess(url, user);
    }
  };
};
```

I tried to get it done with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4568428/459329), but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong there (if I understand it correctly)

- Your hasAccess function isn't accepting any parameters
- hasAccess is also just returning a reference to the access function, not calling it
- the access function doesn't accept any parameters either

It's possible that what you're trying to do would work using

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  hasAccess: access().check
});
```

But i haven't run the code, so I may be completely wrong.

Good luck :)

Comment: Hm, I need the parameters in the jade template (sidebar) to define which resources should be pre-checked. I'm just thinking if I could generate the sidebar automatically on the server, before it goes to jade. That would make things simpler ...